# Is there a better way to handle this dictionary search?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I'm creating an iPhone application. I have a .plist file that contains a dictionary of words (around 180K of them).

There is a textField where the user begins typing a word. As he types, I use the delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to make sure that he only enters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.

When the user first taps in the textField, I load an NSMutableArray called `finalWords` (declared in the header, retained and synthesized) with the contents of the .plist (each word is an NSString). When the user enters a letter, I run this

```
-(void)filterWordsForString:(NSString *)string
{
  NSRange *range;
  for (int i=[finalWords count]-1 ; i >=0 ; i--)
  {
    range = [[finalWords objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:string];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
      [finalWords removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to stop the user whenever he enters a string that isn't part of a real word (according to my dictionary). This code works in the sense that it whittles down the possible words the user is typing as he goes. This way, as soon as he types a letter that makes it so he cannot complete it to a word, I don't allow the letter to be entered. Also, once there is a unique completion, I go ahead and fill the textField with the completed word.

The problem is that this is painfully slow at first! It takes several seconds for the first letter, and not much less for the second. By the third, the speed is somewhat reasonable. Is there a way that I can drastically speed up this filtering process?

Thanks.

Comment: I despise this "intelligent" feature precisely for the reason you cite: it tends to swallow up even valid keystrokes, so it's like typing on a remote mainfame connected via 300-baud modem.  Do you really need it? Your users do not. Don't start looking for matches until at least the third letter.

Comment: Yes. This is the key part of the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scan the .plist file on application load and create alphabetical hash tables (hashing is a way of compressing data into a single value, such that compressing two words that you want to be in the same bucket would produce the same value), which you'd then use to look up the correct bucket based on first 1-3 letters before even searching it. The nice thing about hashing (as opposed to a regular search) is that you're essentially forming an array of data, where the generated hash is the index of the bucket. Therefore, once the data is hashed (which can be an expensive operation, but is done only once on load), the lookup is as fast as looking up data in an array.

**EDIT (more elaboration):**
If you want to look up based on letter combinations, you can create hash tables based on recurring letter patterns. Say create a bucket that is based on a hash of 'der', which would contain both 'spiderpig' and 'binder', then another directory would be based on hash out of 'spi', which would contain 'spinach' and 'spiderpig' as well (in this case spiderpig would be in both buckets). Hashing is extremely fast if implemented correctly, it's the driving force behind most search engines (that's why you see them returning millions of results in less than a second).

Comment: Ok, but then I have a bucket for every single letter (26 buckets each with about 40000 words), every pair of letters (>500 buckets each with about 10000 words), every triple of letters (>4000 each with lots of words) and so on. Is that really going to be faster? I'm worried I would run into memory issues then.

Comment: @iClavdivs: Well, there is always a trade off between storage, memory, and processing time. In the example you gave, you'd need 26*40,000+500*10,000+4000*(let's say 1000) = 10MB of memory. I don't think this will kill your app, since even an iPhone 3GS has 256MB ram.